# What is the meaning of $\rho$ and $\sigma$ in the symmetric group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation, symmetric-groups

In the symmetric group the elements are given as $\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2} ,\dots$ and $\rho, \rho^{2},\dots$.

In my notes I am only given what each one is equal to in a certain symmetry group.

Is this standard notation to represent permutations that are ordered in a certain way? If so what does each represent with their given index/power.

Comment: What are they in the certain symmetry group?

Comment: in S3 they are given as $\rho =  (123)   \rho^{2} = (132)    \sigma_ {1} = (23) 
 \sigma_{2} = (13)   \sigma_{3} = (12)$

Comment: The symmetric group can be generated by two elements $\sigma$ and $\rho$ ( but they are not unique). Therefore people sometimes write $\rho=(12\cdots n)$ and $\sigma=(12)$, or similar notations. Then the powers of $\rho$ are $\rho,\rho^2,\ldots$ and $\sigma_i=\sigma\rho^i$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically $\rho$ is a rotation, and $\sigma$ is a reflection (from German *Spiegelung*).

The permutations in $S_3$ correspond to 2 rotations over $120^\circ$ respectively $240^\circ$, 3 reflections, and identity. They are the *symmetries* of an equilateral triangle.

When we pick $\rho$ to represent either of the rotations (123) or (321), and $\sigma$ to represent one of the reflections (12), (23), or (31), all other permutations can be written as the combination of these 2.